# @Value to retrieve @Query value

Tags: spring-boot, repository

**Requirement**

I've been asked to retrieve the value of a query annotation from a custom property stored in the application.properties file.

**Prievious attempt**

I tried to use @Value without success

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  @Value("${db.queries.distance}")
  String distanceQuery; // this raises an error

  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value =distanceQuery)
  ...
```

Eclipse marks "distanceQuery" and states

```
The blank final field distanceQuery may not have been initialized
```

And force me to initialize the variable as follows

```
    public static final Double distanceQuery = null;
```

Unfortunately it's not what I want

**Question**

Is there a workaround to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining in a properties file, you can define query in a constants java file and can get value as below

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value =Constants.DISTANCE_QUERY)
```